# Finding duplicate using HashMap in java not working

Tags: java

I am new to java.I searched this problem in SO but I tried in my own way.I have map and it is printing following :

```
Key = MX Week Email Pulls 010521 -010621_22780_1, Value = 010521010621
Key = MX Week Email Pulls 010721 -010921_23122, Value = 010721010921
Key = MX Week Email Pulls 010321 -010421_22779, Value = 010321010421
Key = MX Week Email Pulls 010521 -010621_22780, Value = 010521010621
```

Since,key is different,I want to find duplicate of these keys by using values. Since the duplicate value above is:

```
010521010621
010521010621
```

I tried to find duplicate by increasing count value:

```
public void doAnalysis(Map<String,String> mapAll) {
        List<String> listOf=new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,Integer> putDupli=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : mapAll.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                  ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
           if(!putDupli.containsValue(entry.getValue())) {
               putDupli.put(entry.getValue(),0);
           }
           else {
               putDupli.put(entry.getValue(),putDupli.get(entry.getKey())+1); 
           }
        }
    
    System.out.println(putDupli);
        
    }
```

The line `System.out.println(putDupli);` is printing

```
{010521010621=0, 010721010921=0, 010321010421=0}
```

My expected output was:

```
 {010521010621=2, 010721010921=0, 010321010421=0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `if(!putDupli.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {`

instead of

`if(!putDupli.containsValue(entry.getValue())) {`

as the other map is putting the value as key.

Also, `putDupli.put(entry.getValue(),putDupli.get(entry.getKey())+1);`

should be

`putDupli.put(entry.getValue(), putDupli.get(entry.getValue()) + 1);`.

Furthermore, you probably want the initial count to be 1 instead of 0.

If catching those bugs is hard at first, try using a debugger.

Comment: it throws null pointer expcetion since the map putDupli is empty

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, you can use Stream to get the count

```
Map<String, Long> dupliMap = mapAll.values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> x,
        Collectors.counting()
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
!putDupli.containsValue(entry.getValue().toString)
```

As your comapring the values of an Integer to String.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a different approach.  Create a  `Map<Integer,List<Long>>` to store the values as follows:

```
String[] data = { "010521,010521010621",
        "010721,010721010921", "010321,010321010421",
        "010521,010521010621" };
Map<Integer, List<Long>> map =
        Arrays.stream(data).map(str -> str.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[0]),
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                arr -> Long.valueOf(arr[1]),
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Then you can find the count of each value.

```
for (List<Long> list : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(list.get(0) + "=" + list.size());
}
```

Prints

```
10321010421=1
10721010921=1
10521010621=2
```